# Слово "остойчивость"

Tags: этимология

Почему про корабли говорят "остойчивость", а не "устойчивость"?

Answer (score 5):

В Морском этимологическом словаре (Н. Ткаченко, 2017) термин **остойчивость** определяется как "способность стоять прямо" (буквальный смысл) и *возвращаться* в исходное положение ("вставать") после прекращения воздействия сил, вызвавших крен. *Устойчивость* же имеет отличный от этого смысл и характеризует способность *удержаться от падения*. *Ванька-встанька* абсолютно *остойчив*, в отличие от большинства предметов, которые в разной степени *устойчивы*, но после падения на бок остаются в измененном положении.

Comment: Большое спасибо))

Answer (score 0):

Остойчивость - скорее всего, обычный морской жаргонизм. Этимологически никакой разницы нет между словами "устойчивость" и "остойчивость". И семантически они по сути одинаковы. Попытки развести из значение выглядят надуманными. Но раз уж есть такой жаргонизм, то и пусть будет.

Comment: *Попытки развести из значение выглядят надуманными* - какие именно? То, что представлено в ответе Alex_ander надуманным совсем не выглядит.